# Нейронная сеть для игры в крестики-нолики

Tags: нейронные-сети, генетический-алгоритм

Создаю нейронную сеть для игры в стандартные крестики-нолики. В будущем же планируется распространить полученные навыки на игру 5 в ряд. Именно по этой причине был выбран генетический алгоритм, а не часто использующееся в данном случае обучение с учителем (стратегия же в случае поля 3х3 является общезвестной).

Использую многослойный перцептрон с примерно следующей архитектурой:

- 9 входных нейронов, на которые подается нынешняя игровая ситуация. Основной вариант записи информации таков: 'x' <=> 1, пустая клетка <=> 0, 'o' <=> -1. Однако были попытки использовать и другие варианты, к примеру 0.9, 0.5, 0.1
- некоторое кол-во нейронов в скрытом слое. На данный момент 9, хотя данное число варьировалось, как и варьировалось число скрытых слоев
- 9 выходных нейронов (ход делается в клетку, соответствующую нейрону с максимальных выходным значением)
- функция активации - сигмоида

Для реализации генетического алгоритма первым делом создается некоторое число игроков (в данный момент 128). Между созданными игроками проводится так называемый турнир: каждый игрок играет с каждым по два раза (сначала один ходит первым, затем другой). На основании результатов турнира выбирается лучшая половина игроков. Затем создаются новые игроки, но уже не случайным образом, а посредством мутации и скрещивания. Для скрещивания выбираются два родителя (в данный момент они выбираются из отобранных 'хороших' игроков). Каждый из весов ребенка является соответствующим весом одного из родителей (какого именно выбирается случайно). Для мутации выбирается 'хороший' игрок и создается его копия. Затем в копии случайным образом изменяется некоторое количество весов (количество зависит от размера перцептрона). Между новой партией игроков проводится турнир, ну и т.д.

К моему большому сожалению, игроки не обучаются. Происходит заполнение всех участников турнира фактически копиями одного игрока, причем происходит это достаточно быстро. Сам же игрок даже не понимает, что нельзя делать ход в уже занятую клетку.

Было проведено достаточное количество различных тестов. Ну и вопрос заключается в том, что можно попробовать изменить в архитектруе сети или же в процессе обучения?

Comment: Не вполне понятно, как Вы проводите турнир, если "игроки" не могут делать корректные ходы?

Comment: В том случае, если игрок делает ход в уже занятую клетку, ему засчитывается поражение. Теоретически в процессе обучения нейронная сеть должна была понять, что так ходить как минимум не стоит, ведь это ведет к поражению.

Comment: Теоретически, пожалуй, но на практике, мне кажется, это потребует слишком долгой эволюции, до тех пор пока мутации не сгенерируют подходящую комбинацию весов. Очевидно, что в изначальной популяции ходы будут делаться чисто случайно, и проигрывать тогда чаще будет банально игрок, ходящий вторым. Боюсь, что этот фактор будет сильно перевешивать воздействие мутаций, пока наконец веса нейронов не сложатся таким образом, чтобы давать заметное преимущество. Сколько примерно итераций вы делаете?

Comment: Изначально в большинстве случаев проигрывает именно первый игрок, ибо на свой второй ход он зачастую пытается поставить крестик туда же, куда он его ставил на первый ход. Т.е. со случайными весами изменение ситуации на поле почти не влияет на выходной вектор...
Однажды был запуск 10^5 итераций. Однако это ничего не дало, ибо достаточно быстро вся популяция заполнилась крайне похожими особями. И в связи с тем, что они 'думают' одинаково, проигрывал всегда, как вы верно подметили, второй игрок, ибо он ставил нолик в клетку с уже поставленным крестиком

Comment: Меня еще смущает скрещивание, не уверен, что оно подходит для нейронных сетей. Зачастую веса отдельных нейронов играют там довольно существенную роль, а тут вы заменяете сразу половину весов. Получающаяся сеть будет слишком сильно отличаться от обоих родителей.

Comment: Т.е. вы предлагаете отказаться от скрещивания, а также самим создать запрет на ход в уже занятую клетку? Таким образом с помощью мутации мы будем крайне медленно, но верно искать оптимальные веса?

Comment: Насчет запрета - не так уверен, но стоит попробовать - игнорировать выход для занятых клеток и брать максимум из оставшихся. А, и кодировать надо, мне кажется не так. Не x <-> 1, o <-> -1, а "свой символ" <-> 1, "символ соперника" <-> -1. Тогда результат не будет зависеть от того, крестиками или ноликами играет сеть. А в нынешней схеме от одной и той же сети требуются противоположные результаты, в зависимости от того, чем она играет, это, естественно, мешает получить адекватный результат.

Comment: Да, именно это я и подразумевал под 'запретом'. Идея с изменением способа подачи информации выглядит крайне перспективно, спасибо. И пока что последний вопрос, какое число нейронов вы бы порекомендовали оставить в промежуточном слое?

Comment: Про число нейронов ничего сказать не могу. Но можно попробовать отдать и его тоже на откуп генетике. В качестве мутации иногда добавлять или удалять нейрон, а чтобы избежать бесконтрольного роста, при отборе при прочих равных отдавать предпочтение сети с меньшим количеством нейронов.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте [так](https://github.com/cmirnow/Tic-Tac-Toe-AI-with-Neural-Network). Простенькая нейронка для игры в tictactoe реализована посредством ruby-обертки FANN. Приложение не знает правил, но на основе результатов процесса обучения, заносимых в csv-файл в начале игры, выбирает оптимальные для каждой ситуации ходы.

Оговорюсь, предложенная логика нейронной сети, хотя и является эксклюзивной разработкой автора - отнюдь не предназначена сделать переворот в теории и практике машинного обучения. Все это написано, можно сказать, в шутку; программка не умеет играть в крестики-нолики, но умеет выбрать оптимальный ход в любой игровой ситуации (порой при одном и том же положении на доске выбирает разные ходы). Вай нот? - для крестиков-ноликов такое вполне работает.

По ссылке на гитхабе - подробный мануал с примерами кода. При желании, описанную логику игры можно изменить любым способом, какой вам ближе. Сейчас приложение играет только вторым номером; руки дойдут - сделаю на этом же принципе универсального игрока...